# Styling thumb using Blend

Tags: windows-8, blend, expression-blend-4

How can I style thumb using blend. I need to apply a cylinder like style to my thumb. with a gradient color effect. The gradient effect is to be applied vertically with a color combination of gray and white color. I have 0 knowledge in Blend Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without using Blend. Simply add a slider in XAML page & open design view. Then right click on slider, open "Edit Template" menu and click on "Edit a Copy". So the default style of slider will be added in page's resource. Check out below given screenshot for it.

[image]

Now in style, you will see `SliderThumbStyle`. You can set thumb's template here. So I am giving you whole style with cylinder thumb having gradient effect.

```
<Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <!--<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>-->
                                        <Canvas Margin="0 -5 0 0">
                                            <Path Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="5" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 177,190C 176.999,196.903 152.375,202.5 122,202.5C 91.6246,202.5 67.0006,196.903 67,189.979L 67,90L 177,90L 177,190 Z ">
                                                <Path.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFBBACAC" Offset="0.527"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Path.Fill>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path Width="20" Height="10" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFAC9E9E" Data="F1 M 122,77.4999C 152.376,77.4999 177,83.0964 177,89.9999C 177,96.9035 152.376,102.5 122,102.5C 91.6244,102.5 67.0001,96.9035 67.0001,89.9999C 67.0001,83.0964 91.6245,77.4999 122,77.4999 Z "/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalInlineTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalInlineTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackVertical"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" Margin="0,0,0,2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalBorder" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteVertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackVertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Slider Width="300" Maximum="100" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Xyroid, But I found the whole part of the thumb is not touchable now. Only a small area in right part of the thumb supports click and dragging. How I can make the entire thumb area dragable

Comment: try increasing the thumb by 100 x 20 (h x w) ratio. And then try. It is reproducible in emulator too..

Comment: It's working for me, can you please share your code on pastebin? I increased the thumb height & width in path.