# Styling Rectangle or Path in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, expression-blend, blend

[image: Rectangle or path image]

Is it possible to style a rectangle or path like this(Image given "Cylindrical Image" w.o the line behind).You can notice a cylindrical 3D effect in that image. In my application i cant apply a default background image to my control. I need to use the color that is given by the use. I tried to create this in blend. But unfortunately I can't get that 3D effect. Also i can't find a method to give gradient effect vertical plane. I think someone with expertise in Blend and design can help me. 
I found something similar to my question here in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300602/styling-thumb-using-blend) But that solution didn't solve  my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Stephan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a LinearGradientBrush.

```
<Rectangle Width="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2F3243" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5E6D" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2F3243"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Thank for the quick response.. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Add more gradient stops to meet your needs. Best to use the designer in VS or blend to help